# xgboost in R have different results compared to boosted decision tree in Azure ML

Tags: r, xgboost, azure-ml

I have a small data set (4000 records with 10 features) and I used XGBOOST in R as well as Boosted Decision Tree model in Azure ML studio. Unfortunately the results are different. I like to optimize recall and I could pick that as a measure in Azure but I can not do so in R.

I used the same parameters in both platforms. I know seeds might be different but I tried many of them. I always have a much better recall on my validation dataset using the Azure model compared to the R one.

I wonder if there is a big difference behind the methodology used in these two platforms causing me the issues.

I also used cross validation which did not help. Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say, without being able to know exactly what Azure is doing.

- From what they do share, they bin continuous features; you could try `tree_method='hist'` in xgb to be more similar there.
- I can't tell how Azure deals with categoricals or missing values.
- Be sure to set xgb's `max_depth=0` and `grow_policy='lossguide'`, since you want to use `max_leaves` instead for a direct comparison.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/two-class-boosted-decision-tree#usage-tips
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/two-class-boosted-decision-tree#module-parameters

Comment: Thank you Ben. I did that however the model gives me the same prediction for all of my validation data. If I remove the max_depth=0 , things are back to how they were before but when I add that to the function, it does not work properly.

Comment: @Fatima, It works for me.  Can you provide your code?

Comment: Here is the code that I have:

    bst <- xgboost(data = as.matrix(Train %>% select(-spam)), label = Train$spam, max_depth =0,max_leaves=100,grow_policy='lossguide', eta = 0.1,
nrounds = 350, objective = "binary:logistic")

Comment: @Fatima Needs tree_method='hist', I think.